# Firebase: The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation. (auth/popup-closed-by-user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Im add an sign up with google button using firebase and then i click on it and choose an account, it works, but then a click on exit button in popup window, it crashes with this "Firebase: The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation. (auth/popup-closed-by-user" error.

here is error description:

```
  119 |   fullParams[0].appName = authOrCode.name;
  120 | }
  121 | 
> 122 | return (authOrCode as AuthInternal)._errorFactory.create(
      | ^  123 |   code,
  124 |   ...fullParams
  125 | );



  80 |   authOrCode: Auth | K,
  81 |   ...rest: unknown[]
  82 | ): FirebaseError {
> 83 |   return createErrorInternal(authOrCode, ...rest);
  84 | }
  85 | 
  86 | export function _errorWithCustomMessage(auth: Auth, code: AuthErrorCode, message: string): FirebaseError {



  280 | // call could still be in flight.
  281 | this.pollId = window.setTimeout(() => {
  282 |   this.pollId = null;
> 283 |   this.reject(
      | ^  284 |     _createError(this.auth, AuthErrorCode.POPUP_CLOSED_BY_USER)
  285 |   );
  286 | }, _Timeout.AUTH_EVENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message when I had my browser popup-blocker enabled.

I disabled my popup blocker (I'm using Brave browser so I actually set it to 'Shields down for this site') and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Firebase auth in dev mode. The problem is due to some incorrect `cors` setting in my local dev server.

Try go to `networks` on chrome and see if there is any `cors`-related error. If so, the solution is to remove any `cors` related setting on your local dev-server.